# python values optimization with constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints

So I have

```
M = [0.06,0.22,0.32,0.15,0.19]
wanted = 0.21
-0.05 <= -0.273*ln((new_M-M)/(M)+1) +0.0024 <= 0.05
```

New_M values are created by optimizing M values as close as possible to the wanted value(0.21), with bounds:

```
M - 0.1<=new_M<= M + 0.1
```

In other words M cannot be changed by more than 0.1, from both sides, in order to get as close as possible to wanted value 0.21, but also there is that constraint on the top as well.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?I've tried some optimization libraries(pulp, mip, scipy) but it didn't work for me, because I don't how to describe constraints and bounds for this problem.
How should I optimize for specific target value with constraints and how should I use that value for new constraint(if it's possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some observations.

1. We have `new_M` and `new` in your formulas. I'll assume they are the same.
2. `Wanted` is probably part of an objective: make `M` as close as possible to `Wanted`. It is not a constraint.
3. `M` is a vector, but it seems all the optimization problems are independent. So we can solve for a scalar `M` (and repeat for all elements in the list).
4. There is confusion about `M` and `new_M`. "*Optimizing M*" seems to indicate `M` is a decision variable. But I think you mean: "*Optimizing New_M*" with `M` being a constant.
5. You have one element `M=0`. Note that you divide by `M` in: `(new_M-M)/(M)`.  You must explain what that means. (Maybe you meant 0.32 instead of `0,32`).
6. What is the reason for using parentheses `(M)` in `ln((new_M-M)/(M)+1)`?
7. I'll assume `M>0` in the following.

So let me try to use more "traditional" mathematical notation:

```
 min |x-wanted|   
 subject to
    M - 0.1 ≤ x ≤ M + 0.1
   -0.05 ≤ -0.273*ln(1+(x-M)/M)+0.0024 ≤ 0.05  
    x > 0 (implicit from the ln(.) calculation)
```

Here `x` is the decision variable and `M`,`wanted` are constants.

Using high-school math, we can rewrite the second constraint as:

```
   0.84*M ≤ x ≤ 1.2116*M
   assumption: M > 0
```

So let:

```
 L := max(M-0.1, 0.84*M, 0.0001)
 U := min(M+0.1, 1.2116*M)
```

Now we just need to solve:

```
 min |x-wanted|
 subject to L ≤ x ≤ U
```

This can be solved with the "algorithm":

```
 if wanted > U then x := U
 else if wanted < L then x := L 
 else x := wanted
```

Or in Python:

```
M = [0.06,0.22,0,32,0.15,0.19]
wanted = 0.21

for m in M:
   if m<=0: raise Exception("M<=0 not allowed")
   L = max(m-0.1, 0.84*m, 0.0001) 
   U = min(m+0.1, 1.2116*m)
   if wanted>U: x=U
   elif wanted<L: x=L
   else: x=wanted
   print(f"M:{m}, x:{x}")
```

In conclusion:

1. The question needs a bit more careful editing.
2. This can be solved with high-school-level math instead of formal optimization tools.

Comment: And yes M>=0. There probably should be extra condition, if M= 0, then price change(that ln() formula) should be equal to zero. 5. Oh yeah and parenthesis (M) is there just to show that +1 is there after division, not inside the denominator. Thank you for help by the way. My problem that I tend to overanalyze and overcomplicate problems.

Comment: `M - 0.1<=new_M<= M + 0.1` is (obviously) not the same as `M also cannot be changed by more than +-10 percent`. Also `M` is a constant so `M` should not be changed at all.

Comment: well, keep in mind that M is already expressed in percentages, more or less than 10 percent would be +-10 percentage in that case, or at least that's what I meant. You think it is possible to make function where obviously M is a parameter  and two other parameters  M_min = 0.1 and p_min=0.05. Or it would be faster to just do it by hand if I wanted to change the bounds? Well, that + 0.1 is easy to change to parameter in equation, more problems would be with 0.05 I guess.

Comment: Nevermind, it would be M*(e^(p_min-0.0024/-0.273))